# Select like from base return only one row instead of all that could match

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to make live search in PHP. I use CodeIgniter. I got problem with records that could possibly match. They are not returned e.g I got two names Adam and Andrew when I type A I will see only Adam I have to write An to get Andrew.

**Code for model:**

```
public function get_user_search($q){
$query = $this->db->like('name', $q, 'after');
$query = $this->db->get('book');
$result = $query ->row_array();
echo json_encode($result);
}
```

**Code for presentation:**

```
function showResult(str){

  if (str.length==0){
    document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML="";
    document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="0px";
    return;
  }
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }else{  // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
    if(obj!=null){
  for (var key in obj) {
   if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log(key + " -> " + obj[key]); //here I see only one row from base
  }
  }
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
     // document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML = obj.name+" "+obj.surname+" "+obj.telephone+" "+obj.street;
      }else{
      document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML = "brak wynikow";// have not found match - information
      }

  }
 }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","search?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Don't use links on your question. Add your code right here. To format it as code add four spaces or a tab character before every line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[row_array()](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html)**

> This function returns a single result row array

Instead of `row_array()` You have to use `result_array()` and by using `foreach loop` you can get all possible result

```
function get_user_search($q) {
    $result=array();
    $query = $this->db->like('name', $q, 'after');
    $query = $this->db->get('book');
    foreach($query->result_array()as $data){
        $result[]=$data;
    }
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Read https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html

Answer (score 0):

You are using row_array(); function which returns one rows.

Use `result_array();`  instead of `row_array();`